# Navigate from a single page to master detail page using Xamarin.Forms Shell

Tags: shell, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to build a Xamarin.Forms application using [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/introduction). The flow of my page will be as below.

1. Starts with the Walk-through page, it is a full screen page, and does not contain a master detail (hamburger) menu.
2. Navigate to the Master Detail page after the walkthrough has been completed.
3. Remove the Walk-through page from the navigation stack, because if the user presses the back button on Step 2, the app should be closed.

[image]

Is this achievable using Shell?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this what you can do is when the App Launches in the `App.xaml.cs` set

```
MainPage = new WalkThroughPage();
```

Once the walkthrough is finished you can set the Application.Current.Mainpage to your shell page.

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new MyShellPage();
```

Comment: I've been thinking about this approach before, but I'm not sure it's right to put the Shell in the middle of the flow. Also, the app crashes after navigate back to close down the app (tested in Android) from the shell page. You can replicate this issue from the following simple sample. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/896948088b16c80517ec566440fa328e20190827134546/5d38b3513f513a0232c7ff8492b066fd20190827134546/cc5083

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: I checked and the App is crashing but I don't know why, I think you need to update the Packages and then try. But this is the only method to achieve this.

Comment: @Prabakaran I just test and found the crash only happens on Xamarin.forms Version 4.2.0, can you check if it is the same on your side?

Comment: I'm going to check it out with some other version. But I can't go with older version because I need to use XAML Hot Reload.

Comment: @Prabakaran Ok, if you can confirm the issue only happens in Version 4.2.0, you can create a issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) for more help.

Comment: Sure @JackHua-MSFT, is this the right approach to take? I mean adding and removing the Shell page in the middle of the app life cycle?

Comment: @Prabakaran Yes, I think it's the right way to achieve that.